# scala play application.conf read variables

Tags: scala, playframework

Can I create variables in `application.conf` and consume by `application.conf`? Basically I don't want to hard code it.

I tried `dominName = "test.com"` and consume with `$domainName` but not working.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use curly braces around the variable name: `${domainName}`

You can find more example and information about HOCON on [this page](https://github.com/lightbend/config#uses-of-substitutions)